# php mysql full text search multiple table joined by id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have been reading on full text search for some time now, I have read some articles that say its possible but they don't provide sample query,

I'm stuck finding a workaround on how to search on multiple table joined by an ID using full text search

this is my minified table look like

[image]

here is what i have so far

```
    $users = User::select('users.*','departments.department_name')
    ->join('departments', 'departments.id', ' =', 'users.dept_id')
    ->whereRaw(
        "MATCH(user_name) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", 
        array($q)
        )
    ->paginate(10);
}
```

how can I include **department_name** when searching? please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think you are too close to your result. Using query-builder (but not tested) this code should work:

```
$user = DB::table('users')
->selectRaw('users.*, departments.department_name')
->join('departments', 'departments.id', ' =', 'users.dept_id')
->whereRaw(
    "MATCH(users.user_name) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR
     MATCH(departments.department_name) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)",
    array($q, $q))
)->paginate(10);
```

There are also some restrictions on where you could use `FULLTEXT` in MySQL tables and where not http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-restrictions.html. It is good practise to have `FULLTEXT index` on column or column list which you use in `MATCH()` clause.

Comment: sir how can i add the column department_name that's from another table to be included when searching, in the above query is working if only searching for single users table

Comment: Ah, sorry, I absolutely misunderstand you. So there is not possible to create fulltext index over multiple tables. Why not just add in `whereRaw` `OR MATCH(departments.department_name) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", array($q, $q)` ?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a 'materialized view'. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view

basically a table that is the results of the JOIN, and the create a full text index on that.

```
CREATE TABLE materialized (FULLTEXT idx (user_name,department_name)) 
 SELECT u.id,user_name,department_name 
 FROM users u INNER JOIN departments d ON (d.id = dept_id)
```

You can then run queries on that table instead..

```
SELECT * FROM materialized WHERE MATCH(user_name,department_name) AGAINST('test' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

---

but...

You will need to updatethe table periodically (or when the underlying tables update) - easiest is just to `DROP` and recreate - Or you can use `TRUNCATE` then `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ...` format.

(more elaborate schemes involve triggers to keep the 'view' updated, or even watching the binlog, and replaying updates against the 'view')