# php MySQL implementing search feature

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, sphinx

I'm having a hard time implementing a search feature for a web based system I’m working on, I first use MySQL **Like** with **%wildcards%**, but it not searching what I want to display, then I come upon **Full Text index search**, it search very good but has an issue on displaying joined multiple tables with foreign key which I don’t know workarounds, then I came along with **MySQL with sphinx**,

may I ask for any advice the best way/technologies to implement a **search** feature to search a Complex database tables

Comment: Please provide examples.

Comment: i had been asking questions about mysql search feature [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270244/laravel-search-multiple-words-separated-by-space) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448152/php-mysql-full-text-search-multiple-table-joined-by-id)

may you kindly give an advice on what's the best way/technologies to implement a search feature to search complex database tables using php and mysql thanks

Comment: You don't actually specify what the specific 'issue' you had. Just because you didn't find a workaround, doesn't mean there isn't one.

Answer (score 2):

Check `Apache Solr search server`

[Apache Solr official website](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

this technology will solve all your searching related problems

Comment: @Densol yes solr can work with php also, actually i am from java background so i have not tried it with php but it supports you can google it for more details ..

Answer (score 1):

I guess the general answer here is you want a 'search index' - an index specifically for running searches. A repository that has all the required data to answer queries.

A RDBMS (like MySQL) is very good for Normalizing data, setting data up in a compact and easy to update format (ie minimise duplicate) - thats great for storage. But queries suffer as they have to do much more work to 'join' all the required data back.

... but for searching a denormalizaed structre may be best. (bigger, but easier - therefore quicker to 'search'.

There are many ways of doing that.

1. A materialized view as noted in your other thread [php mysql full text search multiple table joined by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448152/php-mysql-full-text-search-multiple-table-joined-by-id) - keeps it all in mysql.
2. Using a external application. There are many examples, Lucene (variants include Solr and ElasticSearch), SphinxSearch, and many more. 
   This generally work in a similar way - setting up a dedicated copy of the data to make queries easier.
3. Use an external provider. Ther are many 'search as a service' systems (basically wrappers around the software mentioned in previous posts)
4. Building your own! Its possible to build a system yourself using just normal mysql tables. Basically an implementation of an inverted index will probably be the easiest.

Which you use is down to personal preference (eg, an external app is more work to setup, but overall is more powerful)